# Does someone has experience with Klarna plugin for Cordova / Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, payment-gateway, payment, klarna

I want to add a payment solution into my app, where every payment method is possible (credit card and bank transfer).

I found a plugin from the company Klarna, which offers the payment methods mentioned above ([here](https://github.com/klarna/kco-mobile-sdk)).

Does someone of you already tried to implement this plugin? The "documentation" is a joke, it describes just one function ([here](https://github.com/klarna/kco-mobile-sdk/blob/master/cordova/README.md)), but doesn't describe how to input the credentials, or price tag or other things.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello how did you implement klarna with ionic ? is there way to implement ? please let me know. thanks